# R shiny dashboard Leaflet pop-up grey background

Tags: r, shiny, datatables, leaflet, shinydashboard

I am quit new to R and trying to develop a dashboard with Shiny.

I am adding a datatable, and this is working well. I have manage to create a popup when clicking on a record. The popup shows a leaflet map, however the background is grey. I can't figure out the reason why.

Furthermore I want to zoom to the location when clicking on a row with lat/lon. Is that possible?

The code I have so far

```
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)
library(shinyBS)



##############################################################################
# UI Side
##############################################################################

ui <- fluidPage(

    DT::dataTableOutput("mydatatable")


)

##############################################################################
# Server Side
##############################################################################

server <- (function(input, output, session) {

    mycars = head(mtcars)
    output$mydatatable = DT::renderDataTable(mycars, selection = 'single',  
                                             rownames = FALSE,
                                             filter = 'top',
                                             options = list(dom = 't'))


    observeEvent(input$mydatatable_rows_selected,
                 {
                     showModal(modalDialog(
                         title = "You have selected a row!",
                         leaflet() %>% 
                             addProviderTiles(providers$OpenStreetMap)
                     ))
                 })



})


# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make the map show, wrap your leaflet argument in `renderLeaflet()`.

To zoom in on a specific latitude and longitude, use `setView()`, where you can also add the zoom level. Here I have set it to Paris:

```
  observeEvent(input$mydatatable_rows_selected,
               {
                 showModal(modalDialog(
                   title = "You have selected a row!",
                   renderLeaflet(leaflet() %>% 
                                  setView(lng = 2.349014, lat = 48.864716, zoom = 6) %>%
                                   addProviderTiles(providers$OpenStreetMap))
                 ))
               })
```

EDIT

I've created a fake dataset here that includes the data you are interested in - this is what you should do in future when asking questions if you need certain features included.

Note the addition of a reactive dataset (`filtered_data`), which basically filters the original dataset (`fake_data`) to the row number that has been clicked on. This can then be fed into the Leaflet arguments.

```
server <- (function(input, output, session) {

  fake_data = data.frame(name = c("Paris", "Sydney"), 
                         longitude = c(2.349014, 151.209900), 
                         latitude = c(48.864716, -33.865143))

  filtered_data <- reactive({fake_data[input$mydatatable_rows_selected, ]})

  output$mydatatable = DT::renderDataTable(fake_data, 
                                           selection = 'single',  
                                           rownames = FALSE,
                                           filter = 'top',
                                           options = list(dom = 't'))

  observeEvent(input$mydatatable_rows_selected,
               {
                 showModal(modalDialog(
                   title = "You have selected a row!",
                   renderLeaflet(leaflet() %>% 
                                  setView(lng = filtered_data()$longitude, 
                                          lat = filtered_data()$latitude, 
                                          zoom = 6) %>%
                                   addProviderTiles(providers$OpenStreetMap))
                 ))
               })

})
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! This works. However I am not sure how I can add an reactive expression.to work. The data I am working with has the following structure: name | longitude | latitude.

Comment: This is great! Thanks for the additional code. Next questions I will add a fake dataset.

Comment: @Megan could you help with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59474422/in-r-leaflet-dont-reflect-the-latitude-nor-longitude