# R aggregate() function: Sum and show missing values = 0

Tags: r

I want to sum the "value" column by group1 and by group2. 
group2 can range from 1 to 5. 
If there is no entry for group2, the sum should be 0.

Data:

```
group1 group2 value
     a      1   100
     a      2   200
     a      3   300
     b      1    10
     b      2    20
```

I am using

```
aggregate(data$value, by=(list(data$group1, data$group2)), FUN = sum)
```

which gives

```
group1 group2 value
     a      1   100
     a      2   200
     a      3   300
     b      1    10
     b      2    20
```

However, the result should look like

```
group1 group2 value
     a      1   100
     a      2   200
     a      3   300
     a      4     0
     a      5     0
     b      1    10
     b      2    20
     b      3     0
     b      4     0
     b      5     0
```

How can i address this using the aggregate function in R?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

We can use `complete` from `tidyr` to complete missing combinations.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  group_by(group1, group2) %>%
  summarise(value = sum(value)) %>%
  complete(group2 = 1:5, fill = list(value = 0))

#   group1 group2 value
#   <fct>   <int> <dbl>
# 1 a           1   100
# 2 a           2   200
# 3 a           3   300
# 4 a           4     0
# 5 a           5     0
# 6 b           1    10
# 7 b           2    20
# 8 b           3     0
# 9 b           4     0
#10 b           5     0
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(group1 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("a", 
"b"), class = "factor"), group2 = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L), value = c(100L, 
200L, 300L, 10L, 20L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

Comment: please check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59474422/in-r-leaflet-dont-reflect-the-latitude-nor-longitude?__=976320040

Comment: @DavidAdams Hi, sorry. I haven't used `leaflet` so I am not aware of solution to your question.

Answer (score 2):

You need of course to tell R that *"group 2 can range from 1 to 5"*. Best you `merge` it with an `expand.grid` accordingly and use `with`.

```
with(merge(expand.grid(group1=c("a", "b"), group2=1:5, value=0), data, all=TRUE), 
     aggregate(value, by=(list(group1, group2)), FUN=sum))
#    Group.1 Group.2   x
# 1        a       1 100
# 2        b       1  10
# 3        a       2 200
# 4        b       2  20
# 5        a       3 300
# 6        b       3   0
# 7        a       4   0
# 8        b       4   0
# 9        a       5   0
# 10       b       5   0
```

*Data:*

```
data <- structure(list(group1 = c("a", "a", "a", "b", "b"), group2 = c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 1L, 2L), value = c(100L, 200L, 300L, 10L, 20L)), row.names = c(NA, 
-5L), class = "data.frame")
```